# How to draw social network fast with a lot of data (Visjs, cytoscape, sigma and vivaGraph)?

Tags: javascript, performance, cytoscape.js, vis.js, vivagraphjs

I have to create a social network with a lot of data. I use visJs and the network is very slow.

I tried these plugins: Cytoscape, visJs, Vivagraph and sigma.

Problem for Visjs, cytoscape and sigma

- They are very slow

Problem with vivaGraph

- I can't render a webglGraph with a svgGraph so I can't have a lot of node and edge and put an arrow on the edge.

Advantage of vivaGraph:

He is really fast because I can render the graph with webGl. But I can't or I don't know how to add graphic with this plugin.

With visjs:

- I can initialize the graph quickly because I am able to keep the positions in the database and I can deactivate physics.

The problem is that I cannot make any changes because, when a point is added dynamically, all the other points must be recalculated and it is too long with visJs.

I have and I want something like that (It's done with visJs):
[image: All the network]
[image]
I want be able to do that:

1. Modify node and edge color, size, name etc.
2. update and generate the graph quickly with minimum 10 000 nodes.
3. Layout similar to the one I showed (If possible group them by color)

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to dynamically add quickly with visjs after initialization?
2. how I could generate my graph quickly knowing that I have at least 10,000 nodes?

Is there a technique used to generate the graph quickly with a good layout?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to a simile problem with a sublibrary of VivagraphJS.

My problem was to build a very big graph (All (or partial) transaction bitcoin).

I decided to used [ngrah.*](https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph) module, these modules is very optimized for the velocity.

Well, the introduction to ngraph.* modules, is inside the readme, but these modules give the possibility to make the personal rendering in your graph.

The modules are:

- [ngraph.graph](https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph.graph): essential modules to import the structure of the graph, like addNode() and addLink().
- [ngraph.forcelayout](https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph.forcelayout): Build a 2D layout and exist the 3D version [here](https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph.forcelayout3d)

There is a lot of submodules, take your time to see all.

For the big graph, you can use the pre-computation layout offline, there are two modules that you can use:

- [ngraph.native](https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph.native): it makes the layout offline, make a file with `.bin` extension.
- [ngraph.offline.layout](https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph.offline.layout): it makes the layout after your graph is loaded and before your graph is paint.

And you can paint the graph with a different submodule, like [ngraph.pixel](https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph.pixel)

### Conclusion

I think it is a very good open-source solution to paint a graph and a big graph, In the follow I will post my configuration with my submodule and to end I will post the link to my project and a youtube video.

#### Configuration

- [ngraph.graph](https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph.graph).
- [ngraph.pixel](https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph.pixel).
- [ngraph.fromprecompute](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/ngraph.fromprecomputel): My submodule to load the graph from precomputing file and paint the result.

You can found a video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOAYN3wDvtg&t=3s)

The source of my project is available [here](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/SpyJSBlock.react), maybe it can help you.

I hope my answer helping you.